# Amen to another's blessing while you are in the middle of a verse containing a curse

Tags: halacha, tefilla, blessing, amen, curse

Sometimes it happens that you find yourself in the middle of a posuk containg a curse - for example [Dvarim 11:17](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/showrashi/false/aid/9975/jewish/Chapter-11.htm)

> And the wrath of the Lord will be kindled against you, and He will
>   close off the heavens, and there will be no rain, and the ground will
>   not give its produce ...

Now if at that point you hear someone else saying a bracha where the law would be that you must respond 'amen'...

In *this* case are there any issues?

I mean, even though you obviously have in mind that you are responding to the blessing and not to the words that you have just said in the posuk...

Should one possibly have to say something else or make a slight pause before responding amen?

Comment: What's wrong with just saying Amen regularly?

Comment: Well, maybe nothing's wrong... that's what I'm asking. After all if you've just said 'And the wrath of the Lord will be kindled against you..' - maybe there could be an issue  about answering Amen immediately.

Comment: That's not why you're asking. You're asking because you suspect there might be something wrong but you aren't sure if it is wrong. Including whatever you think might be the problem will generally speaking improve your question.